# How to create multiple inner joins using Django ORM?

Tags: django, orm, inner-join

I'm struggling to find documentation and examples to solve the following dilemma. I have two tables, Results (which contain results of a race) and Photos (where each photo contain runners in that race). Both tables contain entrant_numbers, i.e. the number of the runner in the race and the number of the runner in the photo. In SQL I joined them like so to get the total number of photo captures per runner.

```
SELECT * FROM Photo p 
INNER JOIN Result r ON p.entrant_number=r.entrant_number AND p.race_year=r.race_year
WHERE r.user_id=123
```

My models are structured like so;

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    race_id = models.ForeignKey('Race')
    url_pre_string = models.CharField("URL pre-string", max_length=255)
    filename = models.CharField("Filename", max_length=100)
    extension = models.CharField("File extensions", max_length=4)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Race(models.Model):
    race_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    race_year = models.PositiveIntegerField("Race year", null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Result(models.Model):
    result_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    race_id = models.ForeignKey('Race')
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField("Position", default=0)
    entrant_number = models.PositiveIntegerField("Entrant number", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The most recent query I tried was;

```
photo_captures = Photo.objects.filter(result__user_id_id=current_user.id)
```

I was hoping this would traverse back through result and filter on the current user id.

Comment: As I understand it, each runner is a `User` and they can take part of multiple races. In each race they have a different `entrant_number` that is unique to the race, and all you want to do is to get all the `Photo` of a user from a specific race. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually I need all the photos across all the races. The tables need to be linked by entrant_number and race_year in order to make the photos unique for that user as a user can have different race numbers each year (hence the multiple joins).

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables by performing a raw SQL query.

You can check how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

```
from django.db import connection
def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("select *
                from myapp_photo p
                inner join myapp_result r ON 
                p.entrant_number=r.entrant_number AND 
                p.race_year=r.race_year
                WHERE r.user_id=123")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

**Alternate way:**
You can set foreign key in Photo model to Result model, following this you will have unique photos of the different results. Something like this :

```
class Result(models.Model):
    results_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField("Position", default=0)
    entrant_number = models.PositiveIntegerField("Entrant number", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_year = models.PositiveIntegerField("Race year", default=0)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    result= models.ForeignKey(Result)
    photo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url_pre_string = models.CharField("URL pre-string", max_length=255)
    filename = models.CharField("Filename", max_length=100)
    extension = models.CharField("File extensions", max_length=4)
    entrant_number = models.PositiveIntegerField("Entrant number", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_year = models.PositiveIntegerField("Race year", default=0)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and then to fetch the photos for a particular result of year for a single user you can do

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter(entrant_number = result__entrant_number,
                              race_year = result__race_year,
                              result__user_id = 123)
```

ofcourse i haven't tested this but this should do the trick. let me know if this works or if you need any help.